# Some cocos2d-x libraries not being found by the android compilier

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have included the cocos-ext.h in one of my header files and added the extension namespace. Visual studio has no issue with the code, successfully finding it, however, when I go into the terminal and try to compile for android, it says file cannot be found in the extention include file. Is there somewhere I need to put the file? Or add it to Android.mk?

I am running cocos2d-x 3.0r2 with code in C++

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the exact error message please, and the line where the error occurs?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The error, I can't copy and paste from here, but was "'cocos-ext.h': No such file or directory" and the line it had the error was '#include "cocos-ext.h"' I can run it on my home machine later to give you the full error if you need.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The actual error code is here: "In file included from jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:3:0: jni/../../Classes/MainMenuScene.h:5:23 fatal error: cocos-ext.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos-ext.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated."

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else encounters this problem, check this page:
[cocos forums](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/44673)

The meat of it is to include the header at the top of your file:

```
#include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"
```

Then add the extensions to the Android.mk file in the jni folder:

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static // add this

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,2d)
$(call import-module,audio/android)
$(call import-module,Box2D)
$(call import-module,extensions) // add this
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your header search paths set for compiling from a terminal? I'd check Visual Studio for where it is searching and make sure the same path is set when compiling from the terminal.

Have a look here: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android

Answer (score 0):

FYI Since I was having this problem as well:

Include:

```
#include "cocos-ext.h"
```

In Android.mk make sure you have:

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

**AND:**

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../extensions
```

to wherever extensions is for you.

Hopefully this helps.

Original Post: http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/simple/?t201982.html